# How to open the door in the Central Basement on the path to the Western Fields?

Tags: wasteland-2

On my quest to spread the cure on the Agriculture Center, I want to go to the Western Fields. Yet this door pictured on the screenshot will not open. I can neither use the lockskill nor shoot my way through. I am stuck on the Central Basement.

How to proceed?

[image: Screenshot showcasing the door that won't open.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to repair this door first. Then I could lockpick it.

Comment: Interesting, I never had to do that.  Did it get damaged in combat, do you think?

Comment: @chaos I suspect a failed lockpick. If weapons were involved, it most likely was myself shooting them to open that got the lock damaged.

Comment: Brute Force is also a possibility in such a circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

You can open it using Lock Picking or Brute Force. In the beta, it was Alarm Disarming instead of Lock Picking. If you fail, you might need to repair it before you can try again.